# Keras models training taking up more time after some time

Tags: python, machine-learning, time, deployment, keras

I have a link to a database of 500 users. From these users, data is extracted. Total training dataset size for each user is `[6000*4]` i.e. 4 features and 6000 training examples. A neural network is trained for each of these users.

Here is a brief code of what is happening in the code:

```
user_list = get_users_list()

for each_user in user_list:
   is_succesful = run_model(each_user)

def run_model():
   training_data = extract_data() # 6000 * 4 samples
   X_nn,Y_nn = training_data[:,0],training_data[:,1]
   start_time = time.time()
   model = fit_nn(X_nn,Y,nb_epoch = 200,batch_size = 20) # code of this is appended below
   end_time = time.time()
   duration = end_time - start_time
   print(str(duration))
   model.save_model('some_model')
   return True
```

The problem that is arising is: for the first 15-20 users, training time is ~ 90 seconds.
But after training of 15-20 users, training time keeps on increasing and reaches to **1600 seconds.** This doesn't make sense because

1. The models are independent (one model gets destroyed before next training is started).
2. Model architecture is the same
3. Data size is almost the same.

So, my question is: shouldn't models training take almost the same time?

Here is the code of `fit_nn`

```
def fit_nn(x_train,y_train,nb_epoch,batch_size):

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(300, activation="relu",input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.3))
  model.add(Dense(150, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(30, activation="relu"))
  model.add(Dense(1))

  optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)      
  model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mae'])              

  model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=nb_epoch,batch_size=batch_size,verbose=2,shuffle=True)

  return model
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tensorflow as your keras backend I suggest calling

```
K.clear_session()
```

at the end of `run_model()`

make sure you add the needed import `from keras import backend as K`

If you don't reset your graph which `K.clear_session()` does, tensorflow will keep adding nodes to it, as a result each iteration will take longer time until the process itself is killed.

Comment: I am not using native tensorflow anywhere. Should I still do this?

Comment: When you import keras does it say "using tensorflow as backend" If yes , yes. But don't trust me and try it with just K.clear_session() anyways and please tell me if it alone did the trick. :)

Comment: I just looked at the code of  K.clear_session(), it already calls tf.reset_default_graph() so you actually don't need it. I'm editing my answer since its not needed. Source code : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py

Comment: yes it does say using tensorflow as backend. I will try this and let you know what happens.

Comment: Interestingly, it did improve the timing but it did not entirely solve the problem..which doesn't make sense.